# "systemctl start" does not start a reverse dependent unit while "systemctl restart" does

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd `fw.service` unit file which is a requirement for `networking.service`:

```
# systemctl show networking -p Requires
Requires=system.slice fw.service
#
```

When the `networking.service` is in the `active` state and I execute `systemctl stop fw` and then few seconds later `systemctl start fw`, then the `networking.service` stays in the `inactive (dead)` state. However, when the `networking.service` is in the `active` state and I execute `systemctl restart fw`, then the `networking.service` is also restarted.

Is this an expected behavior? I thought that `systemctl restart` is basically `systemctl stop` followed by `systemctl start` and thus `systemctl start` should also start the `networking.service`.

Comment: @sourcejedi No, it doesn't. When I execute `systemctl show fw -p PartOf`, then the `PartOf=` is empty.

Comment: Sorry, I think I did not read the question carefully enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`restart` is similar to `stop`+`start`, but it is not identical.  `restart` jobs are treated differently inside the `systemd` service manager.  It is not a simple convenience feature in the `systemctl` interface.[*]

Looking at this specific behaviour, it is not documented explicitly in the current version of `man systemd.unit`.  (At least in my install of `systemd-239` ).

The behaviour with `stop` is documented.  And the behaviour with `start` is also consistent with the documentation.  What is not explicitly documented, is the propagation of the `restart` to the unit which required `fw.service`.  However, I see a hint about it in another type of dependency:

> PartOf=
>
> Configures dependencies similar to `Requires=`, but limited to
>              stopping and restarting of units. When systemd stops or restarts
>              the units listed here, the action is propagated to this unit. Note
>              that this is a one-way dependency — changes to this unit do not
>              affect the listed units.

The hint is that if `PartOf=` is a limited subset of `Requires=`, then `Requires=` will do everything that `PartOf=` does.  So this includes propagating restarts.

If `networking.service` did not really want to be stopped in the first step, you could replace `Requires=fw.service` with `Wants=fw.service`.  But I assume `Requires=` was used deliberately, to try and make sure you never activate your network without your firewall rules being active.

You might hope the restarts are sequenced such that `networking.service` is never activated without `fw.service` also being active, assuming it also set `After=fw.service`  ...I have not confirmed that this is what actually happens. (If this is your hope, I would recommend verifying it based on some authority other than this answer :-).

If you really want to, I think you can set `Wants=networking.service` in `fw.service`, even though `networking.service` has `Requires=fw.service`.  This is possible because these dependencies do not imply a specific order.  I think you can only have problems with "dependency loops" if you have a conflict in your *ordering* dependencies - the `After=` and `Before=` settings.

---

[*] For example `systemd-logind` is [intended to be restartable](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/5600), and arranges with `systemd` to keep certain critical files open across the restart.  But if you only `stop` logind, the open files are lost.  (AFAIK restarting systemd-logind still breaks every current version of Xorg or Wayland, but you can see the idea that `systemd` code is treating `restart` differently :-P).